# ReactJS Like Button

Tags: reactjs

I am a newbie in ReactJS and can't seem to wrap my head around this. I am wondering how Reach knows which case/matter I like when I click on a like button? How come I don't need to pass in the id prop to my LikeButton component? Is it because the LikeButton component is in my iteration, and therefore that component has access to the id? Please clarify for me!!

Here is my parent component:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import Table from '@material-ui/core/Table';
import TableBody from '@material-ui/core/TableBody';
import TableCell from '@material-ui/core/TableCell';
import TableHead from '@material-ui/core/TableHead';
import TableRow from '@material-ui/core/TableRow';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import { deleteMatter } from '../redux/actions/mattersActions';
import SearchBar from '../components/SearchBar'
import Toggle from '../components/Toggle'
import LikeButton from '../components/LikeButton';

class MattersContainer extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <>
      <SearchBar onSubmit={this.onSearchSubmit}/>
      <div className="matter" >
        <h3>Your Matters</h3>
        <Paper style={{ overflow:'hidden',margin: '5px', display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>
        <Table>
          <TableHead>
            <TableRow>
              <TableCell>Toggle</TableCell>
              <TableCell>Matter</TableCell>
              <TableCell>Client</TableCell>
            </TableRow>
          </TableHead>
          <TableBody>
          {this.props.matters.map(matter => (
              <TableRow key={matter.id} >
                <TableCell>
                  <Toggle />
                </TableCell>
                <TableCell>
                    <Link to={`/matters/${matter.id}`}>{matter.case_title} </Link>                
                </TableCell>
                <TableCell>
                    {matter.client}
                </TableCell>
                <TableCell>
                  **<LikeButton />**
                </TableCell>
              </TableRow>
          ))}
          </TableBody>
        </Table>   
        </Paper>
        
      </div>
      </>
    )
  }
}

const mSTP = state => {
  return {
    matters: state.matterReducer.matters
  }
}

const mDTP = dispatch => ({
  deleteMatter: (id) => dispatch(deleteMatter(id)),
});

export default connect(mSTP, mDTP)(MattersContainer);
```

This is my LikeButton.js Component:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class LikeButton extends Component {

    state = {
        likes: 0
    }

    addLike = () => {
        this.setState({
            likes: this.state.likes + 1
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <button onClick={this.addLike}
            >Likes: {this.state.likes}</button>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you pass id to LikeButton

Comment: You're using `map` to iterate on array so every new Like button has a different instance. So If you click on a button then because of its `scope` button knows to increment the respective state on click of that button

Answer (score 0):

As `this.props.matters` is an array, so you are iterating using `map` and as result, you'd get an array that's get rendered. So let say there are 5 elements and each one of them has `LikeButton`, So React creates an instance and each instance has a separate `state`, `props`, and `JSX. So when you click on a button the button increment the respective scope state.

```
{this.props.matters.map(matter => (
              <TableRow key={matter.id} >
                <TableCell>
                  <Toggle />
                </TableCell>
                <TableCell>
                    <Link to={`/matters/${matter.id}`}>{matter.case_title} </Link>                
                </TableCell>
                <TableCell>
                    {matter.client}
                </TableCell>
                <TableCell>
                  **<LikeButton />**
                </TableCell>
              </TableRow>
          ))}
```